# The maximum distance between two successive coprimes of n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am exploring the symmetries and distribution of the coprimes of a natural number $n$. Does anyone have any insight into how to express the maximum distance between two successive coprimes of $n$?

It feels like the maximum distance between successive coprimes of n is close to the number of unique primes that divide n, and should be some function of it.

More formally:

Define the prime divisors of $n$ as $D_n: p \in \Bbb P \land p | n$.
Let $c_i$ denote the $i^{th}$ coprime of $n$: $\forall i\ \ n\bot c_i$

I conjecture that $\forall n \in \Bbb N, \ n > 1, \ c_{i+1} - c_i \ \leq \ f(|D_n|)$.

But what is a definition for f that provides a tight bound? Is the number of prime divisors even a useful factor?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at $30$. The gap between $1$ and $7$ is $6$.

Comment: So I was definitely wrong. Any idea how to establish a bound? It still feels like it should be a linear function of the number of divisors

Comment: It isn't a linear function. Let $N=p_1p_2\cdots p_k$, where the $p_i$ are the first $k$ primes. Then $1$ is relatively prime to $N$, and the next one is $\gt p_k$. Note that for any $c$, we have $p_k \gt ck$ if $k$ is large enough. That gives superlinear, though not by much.

Comment: Thank for for the generalization of your previous example. But we do agree that $c_{i+1}−c_i$ is bounded for a particlar $n$, correct? If I've not mistaken, $k \bot n \ $ iff $ \ an + k \ \bot \ n$, meaning the distribution of coprimes of n is periodic around n - in fact, periodic around the product of the prime divisors of n.

Comment: Right, it was the Bertrand Chebyshev Theorem that inspired me to try to find this bound.

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct. And one should be able to do much better.

Comment: This might be useful: http://oeis.org/A070194

Comment: And so might be [this](http://oeis.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_function) (Jacobstahl function); almost the same thing as Matthew's reference.

Comment: Peter, feel free to post the a description of the Jacobstahl function, the link, and the order of the currently proven order of the function. I'll accept it as an answer, even though its an order, not a bound, with a note in the post. It appears to be the most relevant result to far for what I'm looking for. I believe that j(n) - 1 would be the maximum gap between coprimes of n.